# convert C API call to delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi

I am struggling with the following C code to convert it to Dephi. Let's say the DLL is myDLL.DLL:

```
struct ConfEx_Participant {
   DWORD  dwID;
   DWORD  dwPath;
};

LONG WINAPI AddtoConfEx(
    IN OUT LPVOID lpParams,    // parameter block
    IN OUT DWORD* lpSize,    // pointer to var holding size of lpParams
    IN DWORD dwPath,
    IN const ConfEx_Participant* pParticipant,  //array of participants
    IN DWORD cParticipant   // number of participants
);
```

I am trying something like:

```
PConfEx_Participant := ^TConfEx_Participant
TConfEx_Participant = record
    dwCallID: DWORD;
    dwPath: DWORD;
end;

type TAddtoConfEx = function {
    lpParams: DWORD_PTR;
    lpsize:   DWORD_PTR;
    dwPath:   DWORD;
    ConfEx_Participant: PConfEx_participant;
    cParticipant: Integer;
 end;
```

then in the implentation section:

```
Procedure Connect();
  lResult: Integer;
  Func := TAddToConfEx;
  begin
    Handle := SafeLoadLibrary('myDLL.DLL');
    @Func := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'AddToConfEx');
    lResult := Func(lpParams, lpSize, dwPath, @PConfEx_Participant, 2);
    ...
```

I am a little lost in setting up the structures, populating them and then connecting it all together.

Comment: The calling convention is wrong. The first two params have the wrong type. And you are probably passing the wrong values as args.

Comment: As for any more detail, I don't want to get involved particularly because you've not posted the real code and you've not explained how to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

You function is declared all wrong, and you are calling it wrong.

Try something more like this instead:

```
type
  PConfEx_Participant = ^ConfEx_Participant;
  ConfEx_Participant = record
    dwID: DWORD;
    dwPath: DWORD;
  end;

function AddtoConfEx(
  lpParams: Pointer;    // parameter block
  var lpSize: DWORD;    // pointer to var holding size of lpParams
  dwPath: DWORD;
  const pParticipant: PConfEx_Participant;  //array of participants
  cParticipant: DWORD   // number of participants
): LONG; stdcall; external 'myDLL.DLL';

procedure Connect;
var
  Params: Pointer;
  Size: DWORD;
  Path: DWORD;
  Participants: array of ConfEx_Participant;
  lResult: LONG;
begin
  Params := ...; // whatever it needs to point at...
  Size := ...; // however many bytes Params is pointing at...
  Path := ...; // whatever value you need...
  SetLength(Participants, ...); // whatever length you need...
  // populate Participants as needed...
  lResult := AddtoConfEx(Params, Size, Path, PConfEx_Participant(Participants), Length(Participants));
  ...
end;
```

Or this:

```
type
  PConfEx_Participant = ^ConfEx_Participant;
  ConfEx_Participant = record
    dwID: DWORD;
    dwPath: DWORD;
  end;

TAddtoConfEx = function(
  lpParams: Pointer;    // parameter block
  var lpSize: DWORD;    // pointer to var holding size of lpParams
  dwPath: DWORD;
  const pParticipant: PConfEx_Participant;  //array of participants
  cParticipant: DWORD   // number of participants
): LONG; stdcall;

procedure Connect;
var
  Func: TAddToConfEx;
  Params: Pointer;
  Size: DWORD;
  Path: DWORD;
  Participants: array of ConfEx_Participant;
  lResult: LONG;
begin
  Handle := SafeLoadLibrary('myDLL.DLL');
  if Handle = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  @Func := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'AddToConfEx');
  if not Assigned(Func) then RaiseLastOSError;
  ...
  Params := ...; // whatever it needs to point at...
  Size := ...; // however many bytes Params is pointing at...
  Path := ...; // whatever value you need...
  SetLength(Participants, ...); // whatever length you need...
  // populate Participants as needed...
  lResult := Func(Params, Size, Path, PConfEx_Participant(Participants), Length(Participants));
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Why do you define the pointer to the variable that holds the size of the lpParams parameter block in the function AddToConfEx as "var lpSize DWORD"? Does var specify variant here? Or should var be up above the top variable. Also, why would I not want to set lpParams as a PAnsiChar instead of Pointer? Thank you.

Comment: @F.Decker: `var` does not stand for variant. It passes the param value by reference, so it needs a physical variable whose address is passed in the param. That is what the function is expecting anyway (since it takes the param value by pointer). The param is in/out and does not accept a nil pointer, so it is safer and more Delphi-like to declare the param as `var DWORD` instead of as `^DWORD` (BTW, `DWORD_PTR` is *not* a pointer. It is actually a pointer-sized unsigned integer instead). And the first param needs to be a `Pointer` because it is declared as `LPVOID` (aka `void*`) in the C code.